# Restore not accessible USBs

Tags: windows, usb, restore

Let's talk about the problem. I have 4 USBs from my mother in law which she hopes me to bring them to life, but I have no clue about what steps should I follow. If I connect them to my computer, 2 of them appear like they have a letter assigned (I am using Windows) but they are not accessible. The other 2, can't be recognised from Windows in first instance.

If I check my connected devices using [USBDeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) I can see that all appear in some way:

[image: usb1]
[image: usb2]

My question is, what can I do in order to use those devices again? How can access directly the device, in order to get an approach what could be happening with that device for letting Windows "viewing" it, but not accessing?

I'm a programmer so I have got basic knowledge about computers, so, any recommendation would be grateful.

Comment: These just random devices or do you know for a fact these storage devices should actually work? On the two semi-working devices, that are detected by Microsoft, provide a screenshot of what is displayed within Disk Mangement.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know what you want to mean with "random devices" the devices shown in the pictures are the one that my mother in law was using before them stop working... so yes, they should work.

Comment: Random devices would be devices your mother in law didn't personally purchase.  I would still like to see the disk management screenshot.

Comment: @Ramhound this is what I see on [Disk Manager](https://ibb.co/tCLT1sM) . If I try to format the H: device, Windows says that the format could not be completed.

Comment: I don't read anything other than English so you will have to translate the text in that screenshot for me and specify which disks are the removable flash drive.

Comment: @Ramhound these 3 disk are the removable flash drives, the first one "Disco 2" means "Disk 2" and it says "Removable" and "No media" this applies to "Disco 3" also, which means, "Disk 3". For the last one, "Disco 4" "Disk 4" it also displays "Removable" but the it shows "On screen" label. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Very likely they are all defective.

Comment: Into the trash they go. Buy a new high-quality USB flash drive instead. It'll be a good present, too.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using USBPCAP with Wireshark, but those are complicated tools. If a storage device is detected by Windows and gets its letter assigned, you may try use WinHEX or HxD or any other similar program to read its contents directly. If device does not get its letter assigned you may try disk manager to assign letter manually.

In practice, faulty USB drive is a candidate for disposal, because the reason in most cases is a faulty chip - either USB controller, or memory controller, or memory storage.

Comment: Hi, Ivan, and thank you for your time.

Using WinHEX with 3 of the 4 USBs it says "Device not ready". And for the last one, it can open it, but when trying to access the sectors, it comes with the text "UNREADABLESECTOR". 

I could try using USBPCAP to see if I get some more info about what is beeing exchanged between my PC and the USB. Could you recomend me some guide or tutorial in order to know how to work with USBPCAP and Wireshark? 

Thank you a lot in advance :)